# How to use for loop one under the last row of the other using google app script?

Tags: forms, for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to take data from a basic excel form and paste it on a data table as many times as one of the cells form the form says.

This is the form:
[Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CwQSc.png)

I've tried this:

```
function COPIARPEGAR() {
  var Libro = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var Form = Libro.getSheetByName("Form")
  var CON = Form.getRange('J18').getValue();
  var Disciplina = Form.getRange('J20').getValue();
  var Masculino = Form.getRange('L22').getValue();
  var TituloMasculino = Form.getRange('L20').getValue();
  var Femenino = Form.getRange('N22').getValue();
  var TituloFemenino = Form.getRange('N20').getValue();
  
  var BBDD = Libro.getSheetByName("BBDD2");
  var DisciplinaBBDD = BBDD.getRange('A1:A').getValues() 
  var UltimaFila = DisciplinaBBDD.filter(String).length
  
for(var filamasc=UltimaFila+1;filamasc<=Masculino+1;filamasc++) {
BBDD.getRange(filamasc,1).setValue(Disciplina)
BBDD.getRange(filamasc,2).setValue(CON)
BBDD.getRange(filamasc,3).setValue(TituloMasculino)

for(var filafem=UltimaFila+1;filafem<=Femenino+1;filafem++) {
BBDD.getRange(filafem,1).setValue(Disciplina)
BBDD.getRange(filafem,2).setValue(CON)
BBDD.getRange(filafem,3).setValue(TituloFemenino)

}




Logger.log(UltimaFila);
Logger.log(CON);
Logger.log(Disciplina)

}
```

And as result I always get the smaller number overwrited by the largest number like this:

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHRmm.png)

Thanks for yur help!

Comment: What is it supposed to look like if it was working correctly? Just 9 rows appearing the same?

Comment: Yes, it should show 9 rows, 3 first with Masculino and 6 rows saying Femenino

Comment: Thanks. I think my code will work. If it odes, please don't forget to accept answer.

Comment: Your first loop is missing a closing bracket

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loops are the issue in that you aren't starting at the same rows. Consider running your code in debug mode so you can see your variables value on the right hand part of the screen (such as `UltimaFila = 1`). I looked at your code, and I think this would work with modifications, but again look at your variables on the right side of your code, and run in debug mode.

```
function COPIARPEGAR() {
  var Libro = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var Form = Libro.getSheetByName("Form")
  var CON = Form.getRange('J18').getValue();
  var Disciplina = Form.getRange('J20').getValue();
  var Masculino = Form.getRange('L22').getValue();
  var TituloMasculino = Form.getRange('L20').getValue();
  var Femenino = Form.getRange('N22').getValue();
  var TituloFemenino = Form.getRange('N20').getValue();

  var BBDD = Libro.getSheetByName("BBDD2");
  var DisciplinaBBDD = BBDD.getRange('A1:A').getValues()
  var UltimaFila = DisciplinaBBDD.filter(String).length;

  //Updated the ending point
  for (var filamasc = UltimaFila + 1; filamasc <= Masculino + 1 + UltimaFila; filamasc++) {
    BBDD.getRange(filamasc, 1).setValue(Disciplina)
    BBDD.getRange(filamasc, 2).setValue(CON)
    BBDD.getRange(filamasc, 3).setValue(TituloMasculino)
  }

  //See the starting points change
  var DisciplinaBBDD = BBDD.getRange('A1:A').getValues()
  var UltimaFila = DisciplinaBBDD.filter(String).length

  //Updated the ending point
  for (var filafem = UltimaFila + 1; filafem <= Femenino + 1 + UltimaFila; filafem++) {
    BBDD.getRange(filafem, 1).setValue(Disciplina)
    BBDD.getRange(filafem, 2).setValue(CON)
    BBDD.getRange(filafem, 3).setValue(TituloFemenino)

  }

  Logger.log(UltimaFila);
  Logger.log(CON);
  Logger.log(Disciplina)
}
```

### How To Debug Your Code

[image]

Comment: Thanks fot your Help! it worked but I also had to erease the +1 on the ending point of the for loop. without that it worked perfect. thanks a lot!